# Should I free all the members (which were dynamically allocated) in destructor?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
#define l(x) cout << (#x) << " : " << x << endl;
#define forf(x, fromY, Step, toZ) for(double x = fromY; x <= toZ; x+=Step)

class Particle {
public:
    Particle() {
        totalYield = winRate = 0;
    }
    ~Particle() {
        //cout << " Particle destructor were called";
        args.~vector();
    }
    Particle(double* inputArgs, int nSize) 
    :args(nSize)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nSize; i++) {
            args[i] = inputArgs[i];
        }
        totalYield = winRate = 0;
    }
    double GetAt(int i = 0) {
        return args[i];
    }

protected:
    double winRate, totalYield;
    unsigned int winCount, totalCount;
    vector<double> args;
};
```

Hello,
I learned from my textbook that I have to free all the memory after using dynamic allocation.

From what I learned, **the destructor calls it's members' destructors as a default ( without any command)**

1. My first question is that  **if I use the dynamically allocated
   array in class, should I free them in destructor?**. It is
   unclear because the deconstructor naturally calls it's members'
   destructor as a default. does this execution free the
   dynamically allocated memory?
2. My second question is : **should I call member vector's
   destructor in class's destructor?** (See args.~vector(); //
   should I do this? is this right?)

Comment: Nothing in your class is explicitly dynamically allocated (a `vector` isn't the same as a dynamically allocated array; it's a self managing array-like thing, so it cleans up after itself). There is nothing to destroy here; the default destructor would be fine.

Comment: *deconstructor* -- The word is *destructor*, not *deconstructor*.

Comment: *should I call member vector's deconstructor in class's deconstructor?* -- Not only should you *not* do this in the destructor, you shouldn't do this anywhere, unless you are using `placement-new`.

Comment: Do not attempt to manually call destructors

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks!  do you mean I don't have to call the vector's deconstructor? and then does the class Particle automatically call ~vector?

Comment: @AntonioSEO: Yes, and yes. The whole point of C++'s RAII design combined with [the Rule of Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero) is that unless you're writing your own class that exists solely to manage a resource, you shouldn't need to write custom destructors (among other things), because C++ will do it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I use the dynamically allocated array in class, should I free them in deconstructor?

If **your** class allocates memory, then your class should deallocate it. If a dynamic array class allocates memory, then that dynamic array class should deallocate the memory.

> the deconstructor naturally calls it's members' deconstructors as a default. does this execution free the dynamically allocated memory?

Let's see what the reference of the destructor of `std::vector` says:

> Destructs the container. The destructors of the elements are called and the used storage is deallocated.

It turns out that yes, the memory is indeed freed. This is a good design for a container.

---

> should I call member vector's deconstructor in class's deconstructor?  (See args.~vector(); // should I do this? is this right?)

No, you shouldn't, it is not right. Because - as you said - *"the deconstructor calls it's members' deconstructors as a default"*. To clarify, the members are *always* destroyed after the body of the destructor has been executed. If you also call destructor of a member *within* the body of the destructor, then that destructor will be called twice, which is very bad.

The implicit destructor is correct, and sufficient for your class. You don't need to define it explicitly.

There is hardly ever need to call a destructor explicitly. Destructors of base-sub-objects and members are called automatically when the super object is destroyed. Destructors of array elements are called automatically when the array is destroyed. Destructors of automatic objects are called *automatically* when the automatic object goes out of scope. Destructors of dynamic objects are called automatically upon a `delete` expression. Destructors of static objects are called automatically during the static destruction that happens after `main` function returns. In none of these cases is there a need to call a destructor explicitly.

The only case where explicit call to a destructor is needed is in situations where storage of objects is reused for other objects - which is an advanced technique that you don't need to learn yet.

Comment: Very detailed answer! Thank you. I will not call member's destructors unless I dynamically allocated new memory.

Comment: @AntonioSEO no, don't *call* member's destructors if you dynamically allocate new memory either. Let the `delete` expression call the destructors.

Comment: Oh yeah that was what i was trying to say. I will only use delete operator ! Thank you ^^